# Assignment to None

Tags: python

I have a function which returns 3 numbers, e.g.:

```
def numbers():
   return 1,2,3
```

usually I call this function to receive all three returned numbers e.g.:

```
a, b, c = numbers()
```

However, I have one case in which I only need the first returned number.
I tried using:

```
a, None, None = numbers()
```

But I receive "SyntaxError: assignment to None".

I know, of course, that I can use the first option I mentioned and then simply not use the "b" and "c" variables. However, this seems like a "waste" of two vars and feels like wrong programming.

Comment: What's wrong with `a, b, c = numbers()`?  You don't have to use `b` and `c`.  Why add complexity?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
a, _, _ = numbers()
```

is a pythonic way to do this. In Python 3, you could also use:

```
a, *_ = numbers()
```

To clarify `_` is a normal variable name in Python, except it is conventionally used to refer to non-important variables.

Comment: geez that was fast! :)
Thanks!

Comment: Except when it refers to something in `gettext`, or is used as the tally variable in the REPL.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, use of '_' as a don't care in assignment is a widespread (little-documented) idiom, does it cause a conflict with gettext?

Answer (score 9):

Another way is of course `a=numbers()[0]`, if you do not want to declare another variable. Having said this though, I generally use _ myself.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it:

```
a = numbers()[0]
```

Seeing as the type returned is a tuple, you can access it via index.

This solution keeps you from having to declare unused/meaningless variables such as "_". Most people don't mind unused variables, however my pylint is setup to warn me of such things as they could indicate potentially unused code, etc.